# dynamic Markowitz portfolio

Tags: optimization, markowitz

Let's take 4 assets, whose values are known during a period of time of 2 years.
Then I calculate the expected returns for each of these 4 assets thanks to these 2 years - historical data.
I deduce the optimal weights that maximizes the expected return of the entire portfolio under a given risk (so I calculated the Makowitz's portfolio).

Now I want to test my algorithm dynamically. I want that the algorithm readjusts the optimal weights for each trading day (because until now I calculated my Markowitz's portfolio for a single period of time)

So my question is : if I am a trader who wants to calculate these optimal weights day after day, how to calculate the expected returns for each of these assets dynamically, day after day ?

Suppose I know their expected returns for the period [1:n], if I take into account the new datas at time n+1 to calculate the new expected return, is is the good procedure ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Considered using the kalman filter?

Comment: hmm... I will to think about it I don't well remember about it !

Comment: You could also consider using a ccc /dcc estimator for the covariance matrix of asset returns

Comment: For the newbies: ccc = constant conditional correlation, dcc = dynamic conditional correlation

Comment: Many thx , I don't know this techniques but I will see it on Internet !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out-of-sample is basically impossible to predict means. Second moments are much easier. You can take a look at this post: [Estimating $\mu$ - only increasing $T$ improves estimate?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18751/estimating-mu-only-increasing-t-improves-estimate/18915#18915)

Only with infinite $T$ you would be able to correctly estimate $\mu$. So theoretically your procedure could be correct if means are time-varying, but out of sample I bet your Markowitz strategy will perform poorly.

Comment: Yes it's sure than I can 't have a correct estimate of the mean , but only an approximation. I was thinking of accumulating enough datas to  have a first mean estimate that will use the trader, and then the trader will take into account the new datas to have new estimates of the mean: it's like a rolling window used  for a dynamic portfolio

Comment: Yap, as I said, that's how you usually do it.

Comment: Ok I will try to implement it but why would it perform poorly ?

Comment: As I said, it is almost impossible to feed a Markowitz model out of sample. 
You might get some improvement using option free implied moments.
Check table 2 and 3 of this paper:
http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1474212

Comment: Ahh ok ! Besides it takes a lot of time to calculate at every step ... Many thanks for your answers and reference !

Comment: For a reasonable estimate of expected return you need more like 20 years of data, not two.

Comment: 20 years ?! Isn't it too much ? It can happen lots of things that are not representative of the returns today